# Is there a more efficient way of implementing this cut method for text editor - Python

Tags: python, performance, memory-management

Is there a more efficient way of implementing this method?

```
def cut(self, start, end):
        self.clipboard = self.document[start:end]
        self.document = self.document[:start] + self.document[end:]
```

Comment: What is a type of `document`?

Comment: No, slicing is very efficient

Comment: clipboard and document are both strings

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid contactenation by deleting selected fragment directly:

```py
def cut(self, start, end):
        self.clipboard = self.document[start:end]
        del self.document[start:end]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

Comment: Yes, i didn't see your answer about `document` type